# JavaScript: How to convert nested array of object to key-value pair objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, object

It can be duplicate question but i have tried a lot but i did not get expected result.Could some one help me.
 I am getting an array in request body like :

```
[
  {
    "name":"array",
    "book":[
      {
        "name":"name1",
        "book":"book1"

      },
      {
        "name":"name2",
         "book":"book2"

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name":"name3",
  "book":"book3"
  }

]
```

And I need to convert the array of nested array to below format

```
{
  array: [
    {
      name1: "book1"
    },
    {
      name2: "book2"
    }
  ],
  name3: "book3"
}
```

Note:In some cases `book` can be array or string.

On my first attempt i have tried below code to convert it into single object but it doest not convert nested array to key value pair

```
const array=[
      {
        "name":"array",
        "book":[
          {
            "name":"name1",
            "book":"book1"

          },
          {
            "name":"name2",
             "book":"book2"

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"name3",
      "book":"book3"
      }

    ] 
var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      result[array[i].name] = array[i].value;
    }

    console.log(result);
```

**Response for the above code**

```
{
  array: [
    {
      name: "name1",
      book: "book1"
    },
    {
      name: "name2",
      book: "book2"
    }
  ],
  name3: "book3"
}
```

**EDITED**
 I have made little change in the Code from the **Ahmed's answer** and it worked

```
    const res=[
          {
            "name":"array",
            "book":[
              {
                "name":"name1",
                "book":"book1"

              },
              {
                "name":"name2",
                 "book":"book2"

              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name":"name3",
          "book":"book3"
          }

        ] 
    const obj = {}

    for(let  i = 0 ; i < res.length; i++){
      let name = res[i].name
      if(Array.isArray(res[i]['book'])){
        obj[name] = [];
        for(let item in res[i]['book']){
          let key =  res[i]['book'][item]['name']
          let value =  res[i]['book'][item]['book']
          let entry = {}
          entry[key] = value
          obj[name].push(entry)
        }

      }
      else{
         obj[res[i].name]=res[i].book;

      }

    }
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The added snippet should solve your problem.

The problem in your code was **Appropriate nesting** you didn't access the wanted values and didn't handle all the cases Hence, The wrong output.

```js
const res = [
                {
                  "name":"array",
                  "book":[
                    {
                      "name":"name1",
                      "book":"book1"

                    },
                    {
                      "name":"name2",
                      "book":"book2"

                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name":"name3",
                "book":"book3"
                }
              ] 

const obj = {}

for(let  i = 0 ; i < res.length; i++){
  let name = res[i].name
  if(Array.isArray(res[i]['book'])){
    obj[name] = []
    for(let item in res[i]['book']){
      let key =  res[i]['book'][item]['name']
      let value =  res[i]['book'][item]['book']
      let entry = {}
      entry[key] = value
      obj[name].push(entry)
    }

  }
  else{
    obj[name] = res[i]['book']
  }

}

for(let item in obj){
  console.log(item)
  console.log(obj[item])
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed but above code does not convert the main array into key-value pair(As  the above sample response in the description).So,I have changed a little bit in your code and i have got the  wrong response(I have added the changed code in the description)

Comment: I have removed `for(let item in obj){
  console.log(item)
  console.log(obj[item])
}` code it works ..thanks